# How to call the controller method after directive render using $timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsfiddle

I need to call one function after directive render.
    Actually i tried using $timeout function. But it's not working.

```
HTML Code:

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='module-menu-controller'>
    <layout-render></layout-render>
    <div after-grid-render="getGridObject()"></div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("module-menu-controller", function($scope, $compile) {

        $scope.getGridObject = function() {
            alert("After render");
        };
    });
app.directive("layoutRender", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        template : "<h1>Testing</h1>"
    };
});

app.directive('afterGridRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        var def = {
            restrict: 'A',
            terminal: true,
            transclude: false,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(scope.$eval(attrs.getGridObject),0);  //Calling a scoped method
            }
        };
        return def;
```

}]);

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/k64fyy22/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this? Simple and clear

### HTML

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='module-menu-controller'>
    <grid after-grid-render="getGridObject"></grid>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("module-menu-controller", function($scope) {
        $scope.getGridObject = function() {
            alert("After render");
        };    
});

app.directive("grid", function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        template : "<h1>Testing</h1>",
        scope:{
            afterGridRender:'='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(scope.afterGridRender(),0);  //Calling a scoped method
          }
    };
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6o62kx3e/

---

## Update

Do you mean you want it to be an attribute?

How about this one: https://jsfiddle.net/rt747rkk/

### HTML

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='module-menu-controller'>
    <my-directive a='5' after-grid-render="getGridObject"></my-directive>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirectiveTemplate.html">
   <div> {{a}} {{b}} </div>
</script>
```

### JS

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("module-menu-controller", function($scope) {
        $scope.getGridObject = function() {
            alert("After render");
        };    
});


app.directive('myDirective',  function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
            templateUrl:"myDirectiveTemplate.html",
            scope:{
                    a:'='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.b=123;
                scope.gridObject="my grid object here";
            }
        };
});

app.directive('afterGridRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        var def = {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: false,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $timeout(function(){
                    scope.getGridObject();
                  alert(scope.$$childHead.gridObject);
                });
                        }
        };
        return def;
}]);
```

I'm not really sure what you want to do.

If you want the attribute directive to access the scope of the element (as shown in the second alert box in the example), I don't think there's an elegant way. One way is to use `scope.$$childHead`, it works but variables prefixed with $$ are angular internal variables and we should not use them generally speaking.

Comment: It's not working my case. Because that directive has isolated scope also. Please advice me.

Comment: Please tell me one thing. How to call controller function inside child directive. for example <mydirective>  <mydirective1> <mydirective2></mydirective2></mydirective1></mydirective>. In this i need to call my controller function inside mydirective2. At the same time mydirective2 has it's own scope. I think i'm explained well.

Comment: It's difficult, though not impossible, to use the scope hierarchy to call the function inside the child scope of a child scope. You need not do so, it's usually a code smell. In order to achieve this, use ```$broadcast``` and ```$on```, broadcast an event to the parent scope and let it cascade down to the child scope of a child scope. In that scope, use $on to handle that event. [Here is a tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/k64fyy22/2/)

Just have an additional attribute on the directive with the function:

**HTML:**

```
<div after-grid-render fnc="getGridObject()"></div>
```

**Directive:**

```
$timeout(scope.$eval(attrs.fnc),0);
```

Comment: It's not working my real case.It's executing before my layoutRender Directive and it's child directives completion. Actually layoutRender directive having child directives and also having isolated scope  with that. What i can do for that.